# What are the pros and cons, if any, of selling my WA-registered car in California as a Washington state resident?

Tags: united-states, car, california, selling, washington

I am a Washington state resident. I have a car registered in Washington state. I may have to drive down to California (Bay Area or Los Angeles). However, on the way back to Washington state, I can take the plane. I am thinking therefore considering selling my car in California instead of driving back.

What are the pros and cons, if any, of selling my car in California as a Washington state resident a car registering in Washington state (vs. selling it in Washington state)? I'm looking for pros and cons relevant to https://money.stackexchange.com, e.g. objective financial and fiscal considerations.

I know that the sales tax may be different (sales tax from state, city and county). The local market may be different (i.e., the car's market value depends on the location where it is sold). What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Pros

- don't have to drive it back
- (potentially) more money

Cons

- more (paper)work for you/the buyer

> Selling your car to an out-of-state buyer requires a bit more work than selling to someone who lives within your state. Planning ahead will save you time on the day of the sale and guarantee your transaction goes smoothly. If selling to an out-of-state buyer helps you get the best price for your vehicle, the extra time and effort you invested will be worth it.

> If you’re looking for more convenience than an out-of-state sale, selling to a dealership is still an option.

https://www.rocketauto.com/research/selling-a-car/how-to-sell-a-car-out-of-state